# How to read multiple files and find the difference between the files?

Tags: python, compare

I have multiple CSV files, I want to compare them. The file contents are the same except for some additional changes, and I want to list those additional changes.
 For eg:
files =[1.csv, 2.csv,3.csv]
I want to compare 1.csv and 2.csv, get the difference and store somewhere, then compare 2.csv and 3.csv, store the diff somewhere.

```
for dirs in glob.glob(INPUT_PATH+"*"):
    if (os.path.isdir(dirs)):

        for files in glob.glob(dirs+'*/'+'/*.csv'):
        ## list all the csv files but how to read them to get difference.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas to read csv as dataframe in a list then compare them from that list  :

```
import pandas as pd
dfList = []
dfList.append(pd.read_csv('FilePath'))
```

dfList[0] contains the content of first csv file and so on
So, for comparing between first and 2nd csv you have to compare between dfList[0] and dfList[1]

Answer (score 0):

The first fonction compare 2 files and the second fonction create a additional file with the difference between the 2 files.

```
import os

def compare(file_compared,file_master):
    """
    A = [100,200,300] 
    B = [400,500,100]
    compare(A,B) = [200,300]
    """

    file_compared_list = []
    file_master_list = []

    with open(file_compared,'r') as fc:
        for line in fc:
            file_compared_list.append(line.strip())

    with open(file_master,'r') as fm:
        for line in fm:
            file_master_list.append(line.strip())

    return list(set(file_compared_list) - set(file_master_list))

def create_file(filename):
    diff = compare("file1.csv","file2.csv")

    with open(filename,'w') as f:
        for element in diff:
            f.write(element)

create_file("test.csv")
```